# How do i integrate AgularJS in Codeinginitor framework?

Tags: angularjs, codeigniter

How do i integrate angularJS in codeignitor framework? How to load the templateUrl or template?

Comment: Provide some relevant code with pointing on concrete issue. You should have something done. If you are facing with specific bug you can ask for solving. That way you are telling us what is that bothering you the most, also.

Answer (score 0):

You'd integrate it the same way you would normally.

```
<html ng-app="myApp">
```

And then add your controllers to your views. For example, let's say I have a view for my blog posts:

```
<div ng-controller="myController">
    <div ng-repeat="blog in blogs">
        <h1>{{ blog.title }}</h1>
        <p>{{ blog.body }}</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

If you have data you're storing and retrieving with codeigniter, you can make post and get requests in angular to a specific url to get/post your data. Just remember to echo out the json encoded response in the codeigniter function.

Comment: So i need to use templateUrl in case of template right? and in that URL i have to assign controller url which loads the HTML. Am i correct?